# Access violation writing location in a function of Unicode character set project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

My project is changed from multi-byte character set project to unicode character set. So there are many variable types need to be to converted to match the type of parameter. I created a function to convert `char[]` type into `LPWSTR`. Below is the code:

```
LPWSTR CharFunction::CharToLPWSTR(char charVariable[])
{
    LPWSTR returnVariable;
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, charVariable, -1, returnVariable, 2048);
    return returnVariable;
}
```

However, there are

> Unhandled exception at 0x77a9007e in xxxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x7712311e.

I found that it can be run first time, but the error occurs at 2nd times at

```
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, charVariable, -1, returnVariable, 2048);
```

I spend 3 hours to debug, but no luck. I would appreciate it if anyone could help me to fix this bug. Thank you.

**Updated:**

Below is the code snippet to declare the variable and passing the value to the function.

```
LPWSTR        g_szSystemIni;
char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
char dir[_MAX_DIR];
_splitpath_s(szModuleName_converted, drive, _MAX_DRIVE, dir, _MAX_DIR, fname, _MAX_FNAME, ext, _MAX_EXT );
lstrcpy(g_szSystemIni,charfunction.CharToLPWSTR(drive));
lstrcat(g_szSystemIni,charfunction.CharToLPWSTR(dir));
```

Comment: Where do you allocate the destination buffer?

Comment: `returnVariable` doesn't point anywhere but you've told windows it's 2048 characters long!

Comment: If you're using MFC, just use CStringW: CStringW( "ascii" ).

Comment: Oops, I updated the question. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: No, I have to use Unicode Character set because of multi language support for my application.

Comment: The updated question still does not do what it should. You should allocate some memory for destination.

Comment: I tried LPWSTR returnVariable = new WCHAR[2048];
But there are access violation reading location and Microsoft C++ exception: CMemoryException at memory location.

Comment: @LapsonWong What about `g_szSystemIni`? It has exactly the same problem as `returnVariable`.

Comment: I has addedd below code.
g_szSystemIni = new wchar_t[2048];
But the problem of LPWSTR returnVariable = new wchar_t[2048]; stills exist .

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code presented, you do not allocate space for `returnVariable`.

A simple `new` could work, but in your case this will lead to harder to deallocate mechanisms.

```
LPWSTR CharFunction::CharToLPWSTR(char charVariable[])
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    LPWSTR returnVariable = new WCHAR[BUFFER_SIZE];
    // could assign it to and return a unique_ptr
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, charVariable, -1, returnVariable, BUFFER_SIZE);
    return returnVariable;
}
```

The best may be to modify the function signature and allow the caller to allocate a stack buffer (in a similar vain to the input argument). You can keep the return type for easier use as well.

```
LPWSTR CharFunction::CharToLPWSTR(char charVariable[], wchar_t returnVariable[])
{
    const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, charVariable, -1, returnVariable, BUFFER_SIZE);
    return returnVariable;
}
```

And in the calling code;

```
LPWSTR g_szSystemIni;
char drive[_MAX_DRIVE];
wchar_t buffer[2048];
// ...
lstrcpy(g_szSystemIni, charfunction.CharToLPWSTR(drive, buffer));
```

Answer (score -1):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Caution  Using the MultiByteToWideChar function incorrectly can compromise the security of your application. Calling this function can easily cause a buffer overrun because the size of the input buffer indicated by lpMultiByteStr equals the number of bytes in the string, while the size of the output buffer indicated by lpWideCharStr equals the number of characters. To avoid a buffer overrun, your application must specify a buffer size appropriate for the data type the buffer receives.

make sure you are sending correct values as 4th and 6th arguments.
4th argument is buffer size or count of bytes in the first string and last arg is count of converted chars. and check the output pointer has enough memory.